# Cause of ORA-00902: invalid datatype in my code is?

Tags: oracle, errors, oracle-sql-developer

Here is the code that is throwing the ORA-00902 error:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE collegeManagement IS
  TYPE ScholarshipHistoryVarray IS VARRAY(10) OF NUMBER;

  PROCEDURE advancedStudentsTable;
END collegeManagement;
/
-- ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ --
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY collegeManagement IS
  PROCEDURE advancedStudentsTable IS
  BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter table studenti add (ScholarshipHistory ScholarshipHistoryVarray)';
  END advancedStudentsTable;

END collegeManagement;
/
-- ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ --
set serveroutput on;

BEGIN 
    collegeManagement.advancedStudentsTable;
END;
```

It seems that the `ScholarshipHistoryVarray` datatype that I declared in the package is not recognized when I try to add a column with this data type to the `studenti` table. I replaced the `ScholarshipHistoryVarray` with the `NUMBER` datatype to be sure that the `ScholarshipHistoryVarray` datatype is the cause of the error and the column is added if I use the `NUMBER` datatype. So, how can I get the `ScholarshipHistoryVarray` type column in the table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Types defined in PL/SQL code can not be used as table column types. Custom types to be used as table column types must be defined with the CREATE TYPE statement:

```
SQL> create table studenti (c1 number);

Table created.

SQL> CREATE TYPE ScholarshipHistoryVarray IS VARRAY(10) OF NUMBER;
  2  /

Type created.

BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter table studenti add (ScholarshipHistory ScholarshipHistoryVarray)';
END;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Now, trying to CREATE the datatype, why do I get the error "ORA-01031: insufficient privileges" ? I placed the `CREATE TYPE ScholarshipHistoryVarray IS VARRAY(10) OF NUMBER;` right before the `CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE collegeManagement IS ...`

Comment: Maybe it will help some other DB newbie: I solved the "ORA-01031: insufficient privileges" by connecting with "CONN SYS AS SYSDBA", and executing: "GRANT CREATE TYPE TO DataBaseName" ... now it's quite obvious that I had to do this in order to create new types.

Comment: @Skyp89 You don't grant 'CREATE TYPE' or any other privilege  to a database but you create it to a user (=schema.) or a role.

Comment: @miracle173 I understand now.

Comment: the question is clear, it is useful because it helps solving a precise error and those who have read the question saw that I did some research before posting it .. still there are some guys who really love to hit the downvote button for who knows what reason ... please compensate ...